# SSRS 2005 Matrix Rows not grouping

Tags: reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

I have a problem, The rows are not grouping properly and I am not sure if it is a dataset problem or reporting problem. In the example below how do I get the 'S003' rows to show in one row? Is there some grouping property not set correctly? This report is off the reporting wizard + some formating changes adn drill down. Using VS BI 2005.

Dataset

Year | Month | Cust | Item | Shipto | SaleCases |  RegCases

2011 |||| 1 ||||     DEM |||  B123  ||| S000 | | | | | 0 | | | | | |  54

2011 |||| 1     |||| DEM  ||| B123 ||| S001 | | | | | 0 | | | | | | 54

2011 |||| 1  ||||   DEM ||| B123  ||| S002 | | | | | 0 | | | | | | 54

2011 |||| 1   ||||  DEM ||| B123 ||| S003 | | | | | 0 | | | | | | 54

2010 |||| 1   ||||  DEM ||| B123 ||| S003 | | |   754 | | | | | | 0

Report

| | | | | | | | | | | | |  | | | | | | | |  | | | 2010 | | | | | 2011

| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  | 1 | | | | | | |  | 1

| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | Sale | Reg || Sale |Reg

DEM | | B123 | S000 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 0 | | 54

| | | | | | | | | | | | | S001 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 0 | | 54

| | | | | | | | | | | | | S002 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 0 | | 54

| | | | | | | | | | | | | S003 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 0 | | 54

DEM | | B123 | S003 | | 754 | | 0 | | | | | | | | | | | |

Why is it creating a new row/group for the last line and not attaching it to the third row? The only difference is the year.

Answer (score 0):

Bah.. White space differences in shiptos. RTRIM() Fixed it.